# Why is dense_rank() function assigning same rank to different records?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle12c, window-functions, dense-rank

I have a table TAB whose structure is like:

```
create table TAB (
    TRAIN_NUMBER varchar2(5),
    TRAIN_START_DATE date,
    EVENT_CODE varchar2(2),
   INTERCHANGE_FLAG number
)
```

I have inserted 2 records in it

```
Insert into TAB Values('12987','04-Nov-2019','HO',1);
Insert into TAB Values('12987','04-Nov-2019','TO',1);
```

I want only one row in output for which rank is 1, so I have partitioned the data on basis of Train No and TRAIN_START_DATE but I am unable to get the fact that how can two different records get same ranks in case of `DENSE_RANK()`?

```
SELECT TRAIN_NUMBER, TRAIN_START_DATE , EVENT_CODE 
FROM (
  SELECT TRAIN_NUMBER, TRAIN_START_DATE, EVENT_CODE, 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION  BY TRAIN_NUMBER, TRAIN_START_DATE ORDER BY INTERCHANGE_FLAG) my_rank 
  FROM TAB
) 
WHERE  my_rank = 1;
```

I am getting Output as

```
TRAIN_NUMBER    TRAIN_START_DATE    EVENT_CODE
  12987           04-NOV-19           HO
  12987           04-NOV-19           TO
```

I want only one row which has my_rank=1 and for that I have used `DENSE_RANK()`.

What should I apply in the query so that I get only one record?

Comment: Both rows have the same train_number and start date and interchange_flag, so obviously they will get the same rank. Which of the two should your query pick?

Comment: But dense_Rank() returns different rank ,rank() returns same

Comment: Use `row_number()` is you only want one row.  `rank()` and `dense_rank()` can return duplicates.

Comment: Yep, by definition `DENSE_RANK()` and `RANK()` can return same numbers for different rows.

Comment: Then what's the difference between both if they are returning same numbers for different rows

Comment: Rank skips the next number after a tie, dense_rank does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dense_rank` and `rank` will return the same number as long as the value in it's `order by` clause remains the same.

The difference between `dense_rank` and `rank` is that once the value in the `order by` clause changes, `dense_rank` will return the next consecutive number, while `rank` will return a number that's based on the row number.

`Row_number` will return a different number for each row in the partition, regardless of the uniqueness of the `order by` column within the partition.
If the order by values aren't unique, `row_number` will return an arbitrary number.

[See a live demo on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15c50/1)

Comment: Just remember, that in the case of ties, row_number is not deterministic.

Comment: @Andrew That's absolutely correct. I should have mentioned it.